# Why is the neutrino considered a composite particle?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The existing model predicts it should have no mass but observation says otherwise, it is known that the neutrino can change flavor over time but how does it qualify as a composite particle? Does it impliy that a neutrino consists of many unknown particles that like to stick together but each is vibrating at a different frequency? But I could not find any information talking about the constituent particles?

Comment: Why is a neutrino classified as a composite particle? Where did you read this? Neutrinos are elementary particles just like electrons, positrons, quarks etc.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: I was looking at some forum sites and they are arguing about it so I tried researching but made no progress so far.

Comment: Then link the discussion you are referring to. So that people can put these claims into context and can even comment about the veracity of the source.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the neutrino considered a composite particle?

This is not correct. Neutrinos are elementary particles, neutral  fermions , in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics.

You are thinking that because of [neutrino oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) between types of neutrinos they have to be composite, but that is a wrong thought based on classical physics.

Elementary particles are quantum  mechanical entities, obeying quantum mechanical equations and  quantum number behavior. There are three types of neutrino in the standard model, $ν_{\mathrm{tau}}$, $ν_{\mathrm{muon}}$, $ν_{\mathrm{electron}}$ It can be seen mathematically that if neutrinos have masses they have a probability when in flight to change identity. Probabilities are how [quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) predicts data, and this model has explained observations of neutrino interactions both in laboratory experiments and astrophysical observations. It has nothing to do with compositeness.

Comment: ok I just discovered that it is the probability of finding the different neutrino flavours when it's masses oscillate in flight... this stuff is so difficult ;D

Comment: Yes, it is not a closed subject for theoretical research. There are still theoretical  papers written on the subject